# Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://dev.artifactory.com/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found

Tags: docker

I have good experience in docker. But new in using docker repository with Artifactory.

Currently I am facing this error when I try to login:
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://dev.artifactory.com/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found

Not sure what is missing. I have also installed nginx with the help of docker documentation. Still it does not work.

When I used to login with command "docker login dev.artifactory.com:80" it gives the error Error response from daemon: Get https://dev.artifactory.com:80/v2/: net/http: TLS handshake timeout

Can someone help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: Is your registry https (SSL) secured?

Comment: Yes. our artifactory is running in HTTPS

Comment: Is your service actually public/exposed? I can't log in to this registry, nor can I ping it - looks like it actually is down or not set up to be public.

Comment: No its not exposed to public. Its specific to organisation.

Comment: Hmm, and can you login to a default docker registry? (docker hub)

Comment: No. Same timeout error

Comment: Then do 1. `docker logout` and 2. `docker login`, if that doesn't help then restart the docker service and repeat the above steps

Comment: Same error again. Is it something to do with the Nginx configuration. Since my Artifactory version is 5.5.2 I had to put Nginx for proxy configuration

Comment: That certainly might be a issue. Does your `nginx` configuration comply with [official recommendations](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/nginx/)? especially concerning TLS termination

Comment: I will check that configuration. But it is asking to use .htpasswd file for basic authentication. Our Artifactory is LDAP authenticated. Will that not create a conflict

Comment: But apart from the .htpasswd file configuration all other things are inline with the recommendations

Comment: You should really make your question more specific ;) Yes, it will cause problems, you have to setup ldap auth, exampled [here](https://github.com/larrycai/nginx-registry/blob/master/nginx/docker-registry.default) on **larrycai** *nginx-registry* repo. Be sure not to use docker <=1.6

Comment: This example might help me. Let me check that get back to you

Comment: I also got a similar error trying to hardcode the Docker Hub server at `hub.docker.com` in the `docker login` command.  I know it's implicitly the default but using in a CI I prefer explicit configuration as much as possible.  I think it may just be not possible to have Docker Hub specified as the server explicitly.